# What are the differences in PVP between Bedrock and Java edition?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition, version-differences

What are Bedrock and Java's differences in PVP?

Answer (score 2):

> Update this answer for more differences in PVP.

- Axes do more damage than swords in Java, while its vice versa in Bedrock.

Note - while axes do more damage in Java, their cooldown is also longer making swords have higher damage per second.

- Shields can't be broken through in Bedrock.
- Spectral Arrows don't exist in Bedrock because the Glowing effect doesn't exist either.
- Sweeping Edge enchantment doesn't exist in Bedrock.
- Saturation is a bit slower with regenerating health in Bedrock.
- Java has a combat cooldown where attacking during the cooldown time does pretty much no damage and eats durability, whereas Bedrock has no cooldown.
- In Bedrock, instant damage II arrows ignore enchantments, making it possible to one shot players in full god armor with a multishot crossbow loaded with harming arrows. This is not possible in Java.
- End Crystals work differently in Bedrock and are basically useless because they do negligible damage to players in full enchanted gear. But a single crystal in Java will do more than half health if placed correctly.